# Is it necessary to use cryptographically-secure randomness in order to create URLs for user activation?

Tags: php, random, url

Usually once you register in a website you need to visit a url like:

`https://example.com/user_activate/^random_string^`

Does the `^random_string^` necessarily need to be cryptographically pseudorandom instead of a time-based random one?

I mean is a necessity to use cryptographically secure randomness such as `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or a time based one such as:

```
$string = array_shuffle(explode('','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'));
```

The most common example using the `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is:

```
$length = 10;//Some size.
$token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the bad randomness could be exploited in any meaningful way by any attacker, you should use a cryptographically secure source.

This is obviously true for user activation tokens, since it could allow an attacker to bypass other security measures (like email verification).

Comment: Add to that that the shuffle could be predicted and you got a perfect auth bypass.