# How big must the random string be and how long should a user activation link be available?

Tags: web-application, url

As I see in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/258229/168285) that cryptographically secure randomness is a must in user activation urls such as:

```
https://example.com/user-activate/^random_string^
```

But what are considered best practice regarding:

- The length of the random string. I mean, how big must the random string must be?
- For how long must I wait for the user in order to be activated via visiting the link? If x time is elapsed this link must not be available and user should not be activated, if user visits the activation link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. It depends on different factors, on what risks you consider. It depends on who are you protecting it from. It depends on what benefits can an attacker gain in case of compromising your application. It depends on what it will cost you in case your application is compromised.

For instance, suppose that compromising your application gives an attacker a 1 USD benefit. Then very likely only some kids will try to attack your application. If a successful attack will give 1 000 000 USD the attacker, then very likely high skilled attackers will be involved and considerable resources, like 1 000 virtual machines or hijacked PCs will be involved.  Depending on that in one case a 10-20 bits entropy could be sufficient, and in another case you may need 45-50 bits entropy. This corresponds to 2-4 or 8-9 characters in Base-64 encoding. If you consider more powerful attackers, you may need more entropy. Current computing power used for bitcoin mining is about 2^92 hashes in the year. Means, there is no real benefit in having entropy bigger than 92 bits, which means 16 characters.

Thus, depending on your case, length of 2-4 characters may be sufficient, or 8-9 characters, or 16 characters.

For how long should you keep the activation codes? Consider balance between usability and security. Keeping it longer (e.g. 1 month) increases the probability of successful attack. Keeping it for a very short time (e.g. 1 minute) makes usability worse, because the time may be insufficient for some users.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a cryptographically secure random number generator, that usually gives you a 128-bit sequence at very low cost. The question becomes, why use a *shorter* sequence? That only makes sense if you *type* the code manually. A clicked code could be any length allowed by the server (some softwares enforce a limit on GET size).

And, in that case - if you need to accommodate URL-typers - you might be better served by those libraries that transform a bit sequence into words (also called CHBS from [a memorable XKCD strip](https://xkcd.com/936/)). For example there are, if I remember correctly, 2048 four-letter words in the English language; which means that using a 8K string, you can transform 12 bits at a time into an English word, thus 128 bits into 11 words (or 120 into 10). *"jane-full-date-mite-rote-fake-toll-mark-pony-gaze-risk"* is only marginally longer than a hex sequence (12 bits per quadruple against 16, so 10-11 quadruples instead of 8), but it's easier to read out and type for most people.

As for the validity period, the only realistic scenario is that someone will find the link and test it later: because if you believe that one day more is going to compromise security, that means that your code can be bruteforced in a matter of days. Which you should **avoid** by forcing link verification attempts to be, say, at least thirty seconds apart. If someone is *clicking* a link, the code will be correct. If they're *typing* it, it will take more than thirty seconds. **Fast incorrect codes can only mean automated bruteforcing** (or network gremlins). So, up to a week might be okay.

And of course an already-activated link should become harmless and useless for authentication (it should give you an ambiguous "expired or countermanded" message, without specifying whether activation succeeded or not - that if you're really mean on privacy matters).

There may be other tunables to your scenario (for example... how likely it is that someone might want to *jam* someone else's verification by flooding your server with intentionally incorrect attempts for *their* code? If that's the case you might want to add some bits as anti-jamming: attempts with those bits wrong will be rejected out of hand and not counted in the anti-bruteforcing backoff time).